# Two Ajax forms, one view model. Validation only works for one

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've got two forms on my page. My viewmodel looks like this:

```
public class HomeViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "We kind of need an email address!")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "This isn't an email address!")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public ContactForm ContactForm { get; set; }  
}
```

ContactForm:

```
public class ContactForm
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "We need your name, please!")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "We need your email, please!")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "This isn't an email address!")]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please elaborate a little!")]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

First form action:

```
public ActionResult FreeConsultSubmit(HomeViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //do stuff
        }
        return PartialView("_SubmitResult", false);

    }
```

Second Action:

```
public ActionResult ContactSubmit(HomeViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //dostuff
        }
        return PartialView("_SubmitContactResult", false);
    }
```

First Ajax Form

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("FreeConsultSubmit", new AjaxOptions()
    {
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        UpdateTargetId = "FreeConsultResults"
    }))
    {
        <div id="FreeConsultResults">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="small-4 columns small-centered text-center splashEmail">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @placeholder = "Please enter your email..." })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="small-5 columns small-centered text-center">
                    <input type="submit" class="hvr-border-fade splashCallToAction" value="Get Started" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

Second Ajax Form:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ContactSubmit", new AjaxOptions()
        {
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
            UpdateTargetId = "ContactSubmitResults"
        }))
    {
        <div id="ContactSubmitResults">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="small-12 columns small-centered">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ContactForm.Name, new { @placeholder = "Your Name" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ContactForm.Name)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ContactForm.EmailAddress, new { @placeholder = "Your Email Address" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ContactForm.EmailAddress)
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.ContactForm.Message, new { @placeholder = "Your Message", @class = "contactMessage" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ContactForm.Message)
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="small-12 columns small-centered text-center">
                    <a href="">
                        <input type="submit" class="hvr-border-fade sendMessageSmall" value="Send Message" />
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

I've got everything wired up fine, and client side validation works as it should. This may be overkill, but I also wanted to set up server side validation.

The issue is, when submitting the first form (just the email string), I check if the ModelState is valid, and it is. If you drill down into the ModelState, you see that only 1 property is being looked at.

If you submit the second form though (the ContactForm), the ModelState.IsValid returns false, and if you drill down, you see that it's looking at 4 properties (the 3 ContactForm properties, plus the string email). Since the email string is required, it fails.

I'm confused as to why it works for one, but not the other. I could just remove the server side validation, but I'd at least like to know why this is the case. I could also remove the error from the ModelState, but that doesn't seem elegant at all.

Comment: You have not shown your `ContactForm` model (does it have validation attribute?) or your view or the controller!

Comment: Done. Pretty straight forward, and all of the binding works. It's just that the second form tries to validate that first string email field from the first form.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why your models are setup this way? Seems like you're more or less duplicating a property (email), even though you don't use it.

Comment: The second form tries to validate the `Email` property because its part of your model and it has the `[Required]` attribute and you have not posted a value for it. A very strange design, but one way to solve it would be to change the method to `public ActionResult ContactSubmit([Bind(Prefix = "ContactForm")]ContactForm model)`

Comment: I have a call to action that only requires an email at the top of the page, and a contact form at the bottom. So I'm not duplicating a property, and I am using it. Why is this a strange design? Thank you Stephen, that seems like the best solution.

Comment: See @TiesonT. answer for a far better approach

Comment: It's not necessarily a "strange design", but the model binder (by default) has no way of knowing that your class is being used to create two separate views. It just knows that there is a class with _n_ properties to bind, and tries to bind and validate them. That's why you're getting your validation error; it's building up a HomeViewModel, and then trying to apply that model's validation rules. Since `Email` is missing, that's an error.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I guess my only question is, why does it work for the first form, where I am only asking for the email? The ContactForm is still part of model, yet it's smart enough to know that ContactForm validation isn't necessary. I completely agree that your answer makes way more sense, I'm just trying to fully understand what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply are trying to have two separate forms within one view, you're probably better off splitting the forms into separate "sub views" and child actions, and then using `@Html.Action()` to render them in place.

Here's an example:

#### Models

I'd remove the `ContactForm` model from `HomeViewModel`, and rename HomeViewModel to `ConsultingForm` (to match your naming convention for the contact model):

```
public class ConsultingForm
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "We kind of need an email address!")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "This isn't an email address!")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public class ContactForm
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "We need your name, please!")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "We need your email, please!")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "This isn't an email address!")]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please elaborate a little!")]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

#### Controller

Add "child" actions, like those below:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Home()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [ChildActionOnly, HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ConsultingRequest()
    {
        var model = new ConsultingForm();

       return View(model);
    }

    [ChildActionOnly, HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ContactRequest()
    {
        var model = new ContactForm();

       return View(model);
    }
}
```

The `ChildActionOnlyAttribute` marks the action as a child action. From the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.childactiononlyattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx):

> A child action method renders inline HTML markup for part of a view
>   instead of rendering a whole view.

#### Views

Your first subview will be the same as you already have:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("FreeConsultSubmit", new AjaxOptions()
    {
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        UpdateTargetId = "FreeConsultResults"
    }))
    {
        <div id="FreeConsultResults">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="small-4 columns small-centered text-center splashEmail">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @placeholder = "Please enter your email..." })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="small-5 columns small-centered text-center">
                    <input type="submit" class="hvr-border-fade splashCallToAction" value="Get Started" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

Your second subview simply needs to remove the extra "step" in the property bindings:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ContactSubmit", new AjaxOptions()
    {
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        UpdateTargetId = "ContactSubmitResults"
    }))
{
    <div id="ContactSubmitResults">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="small-12 columns small-centered">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @placeholder = "Your Name" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmailAddress, new { @placeholder = "Your Email Address" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.EmailAddress)
                @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Message, new { @placeholder = "Your Message", @class = "contactMessage" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Message)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="small-12 columns small-centered text-center">
                <a href="">
                    <input type="submit" class="hvr-border-fade sendMessageSmall" value="Send Message" />
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

The "wrapper", or parent view, will look something like:

```
<div class="whatever">

    @Html.Action("ConsultingRequest", "Home")

    @Html.Action("ContactRequest", "Home")

</div>
```

If you inspect the rendered HTML, you'll see that each form is properly bound to only its model's properties, so when you post each form, only those properties are model-bound and validated.